# Total unreadmessage count quickblox

Tags: objective-c, quickblox

Hello how to get the total number of unread messages in quicblox? For all dialogs. Is there any direct api call? Thanks!

Comment: You should first present what you've tried thus far, and any issues you've encountered.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is Working code to fetch total unread-message count from quickblox (Swift)**

```
let dialogsIDs: NSSet = NSSet(array: [])

QBRequest.totalUnreadMessageCountForDialogs(withIDs: dialogsIDs as! Set<String>, successBlock: { (response, count, dialogs) in

     print(count) // Your unread-message count is here.

}) { (response) in
     print(response.error as Any)
}
```

> **If you want to fetch the unread count for particular dialogID then simply pass
>   the dialogsIDs in array like this :**
>
> let dialogsIDs: NSSet = NSSet(array:
>   ["5c500568a0eb470421271794","5c523447a28f9a3ac1f2c1ca"])

Answer (score 0):

Please find the ways of counting unread messages in the SDK Chat Samples.
For example, iOS: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios