# How to get the number of unread messages from Quickblox?

Tags: quickblox

The BE has to send a push notification with a field ios_badge where we need to have a number of unread messages. How should we do it on the BE?
We need to place that number on top of the IOS app icon.

Comment: Your Solution is Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54939656/10150796